# Sending Form to different Emails Depending on Checked Box or Button

Tags: php, forms, email, dreamweaver

I've got a simple form that needs to be sent to 1 of 2 email addresses depending on what the customer checks for location. I am using Dreamweaver with the FormToEmail.php files. 
I have made a php file for each location with the correct email within that php file.

How can I specify which php file to use depending on the button/checkbox?

```
<form action="petprofile.php" method="post">
<table border="0" style="background:#1e1e1e" cellspacing="5">
<tr align="left">
<td><span class="style20" onfocus="MM_validateForm('Pet Profile First Name','','R',
'PetProfile Last Name','','R','Pet Profile Address','','R','Pet Profile
City','','R','Pet Profile State','','R','Pet Profile Zip','','R','Pet Profile
Email','','R','Emergency Contact','','R','Emergency Contact Phone','','R');return
document.MM_returnValue">*required</span></td>
<td><span class="style19">Customer Information</span></td>
<td>Which location would you like to have your evaluation performed?</td>
<td><label>
<input name="radio" type="radio" id="Eval CH" value="Eval CH" checked="checked" />   
Capital Hill (420 E Denny)<br />
<input name="radio" type="radio" id="Eval ELL" value="Eval ELL" />
Elliott (1405 Elliott Ave) </label></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see here is to simply change the form action when a certain input is clicked, something like:

```
<form name="some_form" action="petprofile.php" method="post">
```

add a name to your form for convenience and then do something like:

```
<input name="radio" type="radio" id="Eval CH" value="Eval CH" onclick="javascript:document.some_name.action='fileA.php';" checked="checked" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" id="Eval ELL" value="Eval ELL" onclick="javascript:document.some_name.action='fileB.php';" />
```

P.S.: Though, most likely you would be better off simply doing something like this in your PHP:

```
$radio = isset($_POST['radio']) ? $_POST['radio'] : 'default';

switch ($radio) {
    case 'Eval CH':
        // Do something for Eval CH radio being checked
        break;
    case 'Eval ELL':
        // Do something for Eval ELL radio being checked
        break;
}
```

This way you won't depend on someone actually having to have their javascript enabled. Even if it's not an issue most of the time, I just think it's a good practice to take everything into consideration.